# preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '^'

Tags: php, regex

Consigo alguma ajuda em colocar os delimitadores corretos abaixo:

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+[/]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$', $bloco)) {
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você colocou o delimitador no começo da expressão, falta o mesmo delimitador no final. Além disso, você não escapou a barra (`/`).

```
'/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\/{1}[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/'
```

Outra coisa: quando você exige uma única ocorrência de um caractere, não é necessário usar quantificadores. Então, sua expressão ficaria assim:

```
'/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/'
```

Por fim, uma última melhoria: pode-se substituir os *character ranges* por classes de caracteres:

- `a-zA-Z` por `\w`
- `0-9` por `\d`

Portanto, sua expressão ficaria assim:

```
'/^[\w\d_-]+\/[\w\d_-]+$/'
```

Comment: obrigado, mas voltou um erro : Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier ']'

Comment: Faltou escapar a "/". Alterei a resposta.